# wpf. UserControl size 1280x720. It does not fit into the screen if scale >= 175%

Tags: wpf, size, scale

I create UserControl with size 1280x720, it does not fit into the screen if scale >= 175%. UserControl size can not be reduced. What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. I found the solution, it is necessary to use MainWindow.xaml ScaleTransform:

```
<Grid.LayoutTransform>
   <ScaleTransform x:Name="GlobalScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1">
   </ScaleTransform>
</Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't scale it or resize it, the only other option is to wrap it in a scrollviewer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665(v=vs.110).aspx